I2C pins running at 3.5 V instead of 3.3 V
I'm using the I2C on a Nucleo STM32H723 and have a scope connected to pins PB8 and PB9.

When I use the internal pullups for the I2C, I can see that the voltage on the line is 3.5 V.
If I don't use the integral pullups, the voltage starts at 3.5 V, then drops to 3.3 V after a few ms.

I was wondering if this behavior is normal, or the pins are broken?
Attached image of the scope reading, i2c when at idle.
Attached image of setup.



can you share more details about your measurement set up? which type of oscilloscope problem are you using ? can you show the waveform?

What is the voltage on the power supply rail?

Do you connect these pins anywhere? If yes, where and how?

the voltage on the power supply rail is 3.3V.

I only have these pins connected to i2c lines

You're getting a lot of questions because there's skepticism on how you're measuring voltage. It's likely your oscope probes are picking up noise. The culprit might be that your oscope probe is behaving as a very large antenna with a very large ground loop. To @Andromeda's point, there's no information of where or how you're measuring.

I don't question that you get 3.5V. But with that drawing it should not be possible. But the sensor board is unknown. Either you have accidentally powered your sensor off from 5V supply and sensor has pull-ups to that 5V, or, the sensor boosts 3.3V to 5V and it has pull-ups to that 5V. Now, we cannot guess what sensor that is and how it works, but you see, the more details you give, the more sensible answer there is why the pins go above 3.3V.

Did you measure the power supply voltage with the same setup as the one you are using to measure the I2C line or is 3.3V the nameplate spec of the power supply?

it's the nameplate. Measured the 3.3V pin the nucleo board and it's reading 3.5V. Guess that 3.5V is driving the i2c line
